# how to detect a buffer over run on serial port in linux using c++

Tags: linux, serial-port

I have a big problem. At present I am accessing a serial port via the following hooks:

```
fd = open( "/dev/ttyS1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY )
```

then I read from it using the following chunk of code

```
i = select( fd + 1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv )
...
iLen = read( fd, buf, MAX_PACKET_LEN )
```

the problem is that before I read, I need to detect if there were any buffer overruns. Both at the serial port level and the internal tty flip buffers.

We tried `cat /proc/tty/driver/serial` but it doesn't seem to list the overruns (see output below)

```
1: uart:16550A port:000002F8 irq:3 tx:70774 rx:862484 fe:44443 pe:270023 brk:30301 RTS|CTS|DTR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the kernel sources, you should use the TIOCGICOUNT ioctl. The third ioctl argument should be a pointer to the following struct, defined in `<linux/serial.h>` :

```
/*
 * Serial input interrupt line counters -- external structure
 * Four lines can interrupt: CTS, DSR, RI, DCD
 */
struct serial_icounter_struct {
        int cts, dsr, rng, dcd;
        int rx, tx;
        int frame, overrun, parity, brk;
        int buf_overrun;
        int reserved[9];
};
```

I don't know if every driver detect all conditions however.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this, but it seems, that our system is not updating the "overrun" and "buf_overrun" fields.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Dark Templer,

Your serial driver should update the icount.frame/overrun errors.

struct uart_port  in serial_core.h has member struct uart_icount, which should be updated in platform serial device driver as per interrupts received.